# How to read a value from a h:inputHidden in the managed bean

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF page which has a `h:inputHidden` component and I am setting a hardcoded value. I have set the `id`, `name` and `value` attributes. But when I access the value from the managed bean, I am getting `null`.

I also noticed that, during runtime, the name is changing to some auto generated id.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of the `<h:inputHidden>` is the same as for a `<h:inputText>` component for example:

```
<h:inputHidden id="myHiddenField" value="#{myBean.myValue}"/>
```

will refer to the property `myValue` of the bean `myBean`. So you will have to provide both `getMyValue()` and `setMyValue(String)` in this bean.

So if you change the value of this hidden field on the client side (using Javascript), then the new value will be updated on the bean side once the form is submitted.

Regarding the ID, you must specify the `id` attribute, otherwise JSF will generate one for you (something like `j_id123` for example). If you specify a value for this attribute, the ID of the HTML tag will be the one you specified, prefixed by your form ID. So in the following example:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:inputHidden id="myField" .../>
```

the HTML `<input>` tag will have the id `myForm:myField` (note the `:` used as a separator of ids).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    String myValue= "I'm Hidden value!";

    public String getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }

    public void setMyValue(String myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }   

}
```